# QImage::pixel: coordinate (75,3039) out of range

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

For some reason I cannot run my code due to `QImage::pixel: coordinate (75,3039) out of range`. However I don't know what should I do in order to fix this bug, I tried to search all over the net unsuccessfully.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    int height;
    int width;
    unsigned char *p, *p_begin;
    QImage img("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pictures\\2013-09-26\\IMG_0836.JPG");
    height = img.height();
    width = img.width();
    p = (unsigned char *)malloc(height * width * sizeof(unsigned char));
    p_begin = p;
    for (int row = 1; row < 2000 + 1; ++row)
        for (int col = 1; col < 2000 + 1; ++col)
        {
            QColor clrCurrent( img.pixel( row, col ));
            *p = (unsigned char)((clrCurrent.green() * 0.587) +  (clrCurrent.blue() * 0.114) + (clrCurrent.red() * 0.299));
            p++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use `height` and `width` in your for loops instead of hard coded `2000`. Also iterate from 0 not from 1.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak even though this is right, it doesn't explain how the for loop (limited to 2001) reached 3039...

Comment: looks strange... how large are height() and width() really? If you are getting out of bounds with your loops and depending on memory layout, maybe *p will point to col at some point... we can only guess here. I would fix the code, check if the error disappears and, if not, debug

Comment: I changed it to height and width and the "out of range" still appear

Comment: Shouldn't be the reason for the error, but you have `row` and `col` the other way around. `QImage::pixel` takes `x` and `y` as arguments in that order.

Comment: Firstly, explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Check `ing.isNull()` after calling the constructor, the image being empty may be the reason for what you're seeing.

Comment: A guess: You read clrCurrent, which is 3 byte. (RGB), but you only do p++, which will increase the buffer index only one char. Thus, you do not fill p with all 3 color values. accessing such buffer could cause problems. (But you don't access p in your code... so this ist perhaps not the problem you asked for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code:

Qt 4.x: [link](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp#n4133)

```
if (!d || x < 0 || x >= d->width || y < 0 || y >= height()) {
    qWarning("QImage::pixel: coordinate (%d,%d) out of range", x, y);
    return 12345;
}
```

Qt 5.x: [link](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp#n2225)

```
if (!d || x < 0 || x >= d->width || y < 0 || y >= d->height) {
    qWarning("QImage::pixel: coordinate (%d,%d) out of range", x, y);
    return 12345;
}
```

In both cases, `d` being null is also the reason for the message that you're seeing. This, check `if (!img.isNull())` before manipulating the image. I'm not sure what the rules are for escaping `-` dashes in file paths on Windows, but it's either the dashes the are guilty in your image not being opened and loaded, or the path is wrong elsewhere. Check if the image exists on the hard drive.